# Async N1QL couchbase query using Twisted API for Python SDK

Tags: python, twisted, tornado, couchbase, sql++

I'm writing Tornado application and need to make async N1QL queries. For map-reduce views using [txcouchbase](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/sdks/python-2.0/asynchronous-frameworks.html) (twisted couchbase library) along with [tornado-twisted bridge](http://tornadokevinlee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/twisted.html) worked fine, but I can't do the same for N1QL queries.

```
...

from txcouchbase.bucket import Bucket as AsyncBucket
ASYNC_USER_BUCKET = AsyncBucket(**settings.USER_BUCKET_ARGS)

class FooHandler(BaseAPIHandler):
    @schema.validate()
    @authenticated
    @coroutine
    def get(self):
        res = yield ASYNC_USER_BUCKET.n1qlQueryAll("SELECT * FROM farm_user;")
        ...
```

After executing following query `res` object **is not iterable** and looks like this.
[image: res object]

Seems that `_BatchedRowMixin__rows` field contains the results of the query, but I'm not sure this is the right and stable way of making async N1QL queries. Are there any other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you've identified a bug in our client. It has been filed as https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/PYCBC-306. Our code-review has a patch up which should be merged soon (http://review.couchbase.org/#/c/56402/).

Comment: One more problem with async calls result here: if query didn't return any row, then you can't iterate over it, because `__rows` attribute is set to `None`. I think empty list would be better choice here. And also I didn't find any reliable way to check if query returned anything before trying to iterate over it.

Comment: We just released 2.0.5 -- does this problem still exist there?

Comment: Yes. Also seems that its impossible to make N1QL queries with JOINS on password-protected buckets. I was trying to pass `creds` parameter using following code `q.set_option("creds", [
            {"user": "bucket1", "pass": "password"},
            {"user": "bucket2", "pass": "password"}
        ])` but I'm still getting this frustrating error `creds has to be of type array of { user, pass }`

Comment: I'm not sure cross bucket joins are supported yet (perhaps you could ask on forums.couchbase.com and see what the exact status is). This might also be a result of the client _also_ sending the HTTP auth header (which might confuse the server). Regarding the empty resultset, I'll try and fix it. You can track it here https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/PYCBC-308